# Automated Builds in Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, build, build-automation

I am setting up an automated build for my solution.  However, I get errors regarding failures in copying certain information to certain folders.  This pertains to build events that each project in my solution has.

What I was wondering is if there was a way to "turn off" the individual build events in the projects, or if there is a parameter to set somewhere that turns these build events off?

The automated build I have set up already does what the individual project build events are supposed to do, and so it is trying to repeat itself and is causing problems.  I still need the build events to be associated with the projects because when they're running outside of the development environment, they need to occur for the application to function properly (the build events have to do with dynamically updating information).

Long story short, is there a way to turn off the builds that are associated with each individual project in my solution without actually deleting them?  I need them to be there, I just need them to be "invisible" so-to-speak while I'm running the automated builds in the development environment.

I apologize for the verbosity and for the vagueness of everything, it is difficult to explain things sometimes without giving away too much.

*EDIT: Not so much an edit as it is additional information for clarity, but nevertheless.  The basic goal I am trying to accomplish is to disable the "post builds" that are associated with each of the projects in my solution.  I want to keep them, just disable them while I'm running them through the in-house automated builds/tests*

Comment: You can use the BuildingInsideVisualStudio property to determine, in your *.*proj files, whether you're building inside VS or not.

Comment: I just found that property a little while ago, and I've tried implementing it in the "Post-build event command line" field in the form of an "if [NOT] $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) <executed code>" statement.  This didn't work, though.  Is that where/how you handle it?

Comment: I figured having that statement set up like it is it would execute the code if it's building outside Visual Studio, but if it is building inside Visual Studio it would just skip over the "executed code", however I may have gotten something tweaked wrongly somewhere, I don't know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After loads of research on the "BuildingInsideVisualStudio" property, and lots of tweaking to get the syntax right, my team and I found what we were looking for.

We inserted the statement

`if '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' <executed code>`

format in the "Post-Build event Command Line" section under the project's properties > Build Events tab.

Comment: This pulled me out of a bind today!  Thank you sir.  I'd give you 2 upvotes if I could!

Answer (score 8):

Some post-build script code like this should work:

```
if "$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)"=="" (
    @echo TFS build
) else (
    @echo Visual Studio build
)
```

Place your existing code in the appropriate block depending on if you want it to run only in VS builds, or only in TFS builds

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the .csproj file to something like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' ">
    <PostBuildEvent>commands to execute</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio will not display any information in the Build Events tab, so it might be more difficult for future maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

You could check any of the team build properties and see if they're populated.  If so, you can assume it's a team build.  I use this approach with our build so that post build deployment labeling etc only occur if it IS running on the build server.

Here's a [link with the various team build properties](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/30_useful_team.html)

```
<SomeTask Condition="$(BuildDefinitionName)!=''">
```